# Making a String from a recursive data-structure

Tags: recursion, data-structures, racket, typed-racket

```
define-type StringTree (U StringNode 'SEmpty))

(define-struct StringNode
  ([val   : String]
   [left  : StringTree]
   [right : StringTree]))
```

Using the definition above. We have to make a function that can make a second degree data structure and output a string that is all of the letters on the very right side of the structure.

Making the structure recursive is pretty easy:

```
 (: mirror : StringTree -> StringTree)
 (define (mirror a)
   (match a
       ['SEmpty 'SEmpty]
       [(StringNode val left right)
        (StringNode val (mirror left) (mirror right))]))
```

But I have no idea how to output only strings on the right side into a single, appended string.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the structure of the function is already there. You only have to figure out what to do for the base case and what to do in the recursive case. Instead of a `StringNode`, you will return a string made with `string-append`.

The `val` is already a string, and calling the function recursively will also give you a string, so all you have to do is append them together.